# Can't create pagination in fat free framework 3

Tags: php, pagination, fat-free-framework

using a manual that http://fatfreeframework.com/databases#navigation-and-pagination, I can not understand how to create a paginator ... there are examples of?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help you directly, but there's an error in the sample code:

```
// get all items for current page
$articleList = $article->paginate($pages->getItemOffset(),$items_per_page
    NULL, array('sort' => 'headline asc'));
```

There is a comma missing after `$items_per_page`, so the correct code is:

```
// get all items for current page
$articleList = $article->paginate(
    $pages->getItemOffset(),
    $items_per_page,
    NULL,
    [
        'sort' => 'headline asc'
    ]
);
```

`NULL` is where you can specify a search filter criteria array. This worked for me.

Comment: `sort` in the last argument array should be `order` (version 3.6)